# Xcode keeps crashing when opening a certain project

Tags: iphone, xcode

Xcode crashes as soon as I open the project. What is more interesting is the fact that XCode does not crash on other projects. Any ideas of what this could be ?

[image]

Update 1: I am using XCode 4.2 on a Snow Leopard machine.

Update 2: I have a sneaky feeling that the crash is happening only when I click on the project navigator button

Comment: Which version of xcode you are using ?

Comment: Wrong version of xCode, corrupted install of xCode, corrupted project, a virus, hard drive sector issues, ram issues, etc.

Comment: I am able to compile and execute test projects. This probably means xcode is installed correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Generally when this happens, deleting all the user files from the project will fix the crash.

Delete the following files from your `Project.xcodeproj/` directory/bundle:

- `project.xcworkspace`
- `xcuserdata`

Comment: Do I have to delete any file other than the 2 mentioned here? Also I why is XCode crashing only on 1 particular project?

Answer (score 2):

The crash appears to have something to do when drawing the SCM status (Git, Subversion) of one of your files. Personally, I don't have this problem, so I can't offer a specific fix. Perhaps there is something atypical about your repository's state which you can correct.

You may also want to try (temporarily) deleting your xcuser state data (shot in the dark).

Comment: I deleted the xcuser data but still the same problem. Anything I should test for specifically to in my repo?

Comment: @Abhi sorry, not sure. perhaps a file with a less typical status? perhaps another client (SourceTree?) would display an error/issue xcode isn't prepared to handle.